# cudnn handle not created, solve is clear, how to implement

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ros

Hello I am using ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic, tensorflow 1.13.1.
My aim to combine an ensenso n35 camera with its rosdriver to the mask rcnn node created for ROS. I have altered the original code for the mask rcnn node so that it takes a grayscale input an stacks it onto itself. I have actually already verified this to work by using a **virtual version of the ensenso camera**.The sdk contains an app that sets this up. It outputs a white image, however, this should not be an issue for testing functionality. The problem arrises when I attacht the **actual** camera to the system. This gives the following error:

```
2019-03-28 13:30:43.113919: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
2019-03-28 13:30:43.872243: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2019-03-28 13:30:43.874466: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 182, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 179, in main
    node.run()
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 104, in run
    results = self._model.detect([np_image], verbose=0)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/model.py", line 2340, in detect
    self.keras_model.predict([molded_images, image_metas], verbose=0)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in predict
    verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1299, in _predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2357, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1156, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1354, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node conv1/convolution (defined at /home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3195) ]]
     [[node ROI/strided_slice_20 (defined at /home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/utils.py:687) ]]

Caused by op u'conv1/convolution', defined at:
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 182, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 178, in main
    node = MaskRCNNNode()
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 65, in __init__
    config=config)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/model.py", line 1735, in __init__
    self.keras_model = self.build(mode=mode, config=config)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/model.py", line 1791, in build
    _, C2, C3, C4, C5 = resnet_graph(input_image, "resnet101", stage5=True)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/model.py", line 152, in resnet_graph
    x = KL.Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), name='conv1', use_bias=True)(x)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 164, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3195, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 851, in convolution
    return op(input, filter)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 966, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 591, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 208, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1026, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

UnknownError (see above for traceback): Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node conv1/convolution (defined at /home/riwo-rack-pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3195) ]]
     [[node ROI/strided_slice_20 (defined at /home/riwo-rack-pc/ROS_Mask_rcnn/src/mask_rcnn_ros/src/mask_rcnn_ros/utils.py:687) ]]
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out where this goes into error nor why. I was ensured that the virtual camera outputs the same data as the actual would, but the error only occurs when using the actual camera.

What i have found so far is that the following statement should be added somewhere in the code but I can not think of, or find, the proper placement for it:

```
config_pb2.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
```

Help would be much appreciated! Also if anyone thinks this question is better asked elsewhere I will move it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you are using python=2.7, in the Mask-Rcnn documentation requires.

> python_requires='>=3.4',

Other things you should consider.

If you're trying to use your gpu you shloud use tensorflow-gpu.

> $ pip install tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Thanks for the respons, however, the mask rcnn code only really needs python 3 to train the model weights. It can then be used just fine with python2.7. The reason why I am using python 2.7 is because ROS is incompatible with python 3. The mask-rcnn-node was created for inference only. I have installed tensorflow gpu, and it works perfectly fine. The eventual answer to my problem was adding two lines of code in tensorflow_backend.py a python script belonging to the keras API.